# mouseover and mouseout events in javascript not working in proper manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a div which pops up on mouseover over its parent div and disappears on mouseout. But when I entered the mouse in that div area, its not showing a clear increase in the height rather its height flickers up and down continuously on even a slight movement of the mouse within the area(i.e., mouse was not taken out of the area while sliding).

See the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur3291/xN5bS/

Firstly, I want to know how the mouseover and mouseout event works (their true meanings) and secondly, what is the remedy for it? I am basically finding the solution in pure javascript but jQuery code is also appreciable. See my full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>js height check</title>
<style type="text/css">
#box{display:block;height:200px;width:200px;border:1px solid #000;position:relative;}
#inner{display:none;height:0;opacity:0.6;background-color:#000;width:200px;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function heightUp()
{
var h=20;
var obj=document.getElementById("inner");
obj.style.display="block";
function frame()
{
    h=h+5;
    obj.style.height=h+"px";
    if(h>=150)
        clearInterval(timer1);
}
var timer1=setInterval(frame,10);
}
function heightDown()
{
var obj=document.getElementById("inner");
var h=parseInt(obj.style.height);
document.getElementById("matter").innerHTML=h;
function frame()
{
    h=h-5;
    obj.style.height=h+"px";
    if(h>=30)
    {
        obj.style.display="none";
        clearInterval(timer2);
    }
}
var timer2=setInterval(frame,10);
//obj.style.height-=100+'px';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box" onmouseover="heightUp()" onmouseout="heightDown()">
<div id="inner">
</div>
</div>
<p id="matter">h</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the events do respectively

- **MouseOver**: A mouse passes over this element (this keeps calling while you move the mouse over this element thats the problem)
- **MouseOut**: A mouse leaves the area of the element

but the best and easiest way to archieve the effect you want is doing it by jquery as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box").hover(function(){
    //Mouse Enter

    $("#inner").animate({height: "200px"}, 500);
  },function(){
    //Mouse Leaves

    $("#inner").clearQueue();
    $("#inner").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
  });

});
```

working link
http://jsfiddle.net/xN5bS/1/

Comment: You should remove the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` declarations in the HTML on your fiddle since they're no longer being used.

Comment: Also, arguably, the easiest way to fix is to just add `pointer-events: none` to the CSS for `#inner`, but I digress :)

Comment: i forgot to remove the calls from HTML :), and you may be right about the easiest way, but with jquery is simpler since you have the framework doing the animation for you it, in the end the best way depends the purpose of the code right?

Comment: Ankur Shah, clear the animation stack, if you rapdly move the mouse over the div you create a stack of calls that can broke the page! clearQueue() prevents the creation of this stack

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that when `inner` rises to the point of your cursor, since it's "on top" of the `box` element, you are no longer technically "over" the `box` element.  Ergo, the `mouseout` event fires.

If you add `pointer-events: none` to your CSS declaration for `inner`, this will work since you're telling that element to ignore pointer events.  This way the obscured element (`box`) will receive the events.

Here's a [a fiddle with it fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/76BuQ/1/).

Also you shouldn't use the `onmouseover` or `onmouseout` HTML attributes when assigning event handlers, rather do it via the `addEventListener` interface. (Which is `attachEvent` in IE8, btw)

Comment: Actually I want to put some links in that black popup div, so making `pointer-events:none` will make the anchor tags useless(unable to work)...else your code is working fine...but the purpose is not resolved. Just imagine a gallery of photos and on taking a pointer on the photo a black transparent screen comes out with some actions written on it, and we can click any of the options for an event to occur.